# Upload swf and get width and height using HTML5 File API

Tags: javascript, html, upload, flash, fileapi

What is the best way to read width and height of an uploaded swf file using HTML5 File API?

The best tip I have found in my research was to get url from `window.URL.createObjectURL(file)` in order to pass it to the src attribute of a dynamically created embed element. Then obtain width and height.

Do you see any better solution?

Comment: What version of flash is the SWF created with and is the file compressed or not?

Comment: I need to be prepared for every case.

Answer (score 1):

Each swf file has FrameSize in the header. If you find the way to read first bytes from swf file you will see the answer.

You have to follow those steps:

1. open swf as binary file
2. skip first bytes (signature, version, file size)
3. next bytes contain frame size

See [SWF File format specification](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/swf-file-format-spec.pdf) for more information.

Comment: could you present some demo?

Comment: You have to do the following steps:
1) open swf as binary file
2) skip first bytes (signature, version, file size) 
3) next bytes contain frame size

you can read full SWF Specification here http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/swf/pdf/swf-file-format-spec.pdf
or brief description about headers http://www.the-labs.com/MacromediaFlash/SWF-Spec/SWFfileformat.html

Comment: Hi @shaun, put this detail in the answer, then it will become more useful - and give more detail about the link, see [answer].